# Python BeautifulSoup string to float

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup

I have downloaded a data set in xml format from online webpage. I have extracted the values tag using beautifulsoup library of python. This gives me unicode values.

```
graphs = soup.graphs
c = 0
for q in graphs:
    name = q['title']
    data = {}

    for r in graphs.contents[c]:
        print float(str(unicode(r.string)))
        data[r['xid']] = unicode(r.string)
    c = c + 1

    result[name] = [data[k] for k in key]
```

The Source is http://charts.realclearpolitics.com/charts/1171.xml

And I want to make r.string float type

So I did

```
print float(str(unicode(r.string)))
print float(unicode(r.string))
```

But I met this err

```
File "<ipython-input-142-cf14a8845443>", line 73
    print float(unicode(r.string)))
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How could i do?

Comment: float(r.string) also have Err
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Comment: This appears to be off-topic as it was caused by an irreproducible typographical error.

Comment: So, How can I change type None to any type??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First error is imbalanced round brackets.

```
print float(str(unicode(r.string))))
                                   ^ 4th here
```

Second error, check the value whether its None or not before making the operation. Otherwise you'll get error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: None`

So the fix will be:

```
if(r.string != None):
    print float(str(unicode(r.string)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is because of unbalanced parentheses (remove one from right). `r.string` is probably `None`, hence the `TypeError`